# Sorting of array keys in which keys are labeled Apr 16-30, May 1-15

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I got an array with keys of their month group

```
$array = [
  'Apr 1-15' => [],
  'May 1-15' => [],
  'Apr 16-30 => [],
 ];
```

I want to sort them in this way,

```
$array = [
  'Apr 1-15' => [],
  'Apr 16-30 => [],
  'May 1-15' => [],
 ];
```

What I did now is this:

```
uksort($data, function ($a, $b) {
  $a = explode(' ', $a);
  $b = explode(' ', $b);
  return strcasecmp($a[0], $b[0]);
});
```

But I still can't sort them in the right way. Any help to fix this? Thanks

Comment: If you want to sort alphabetically, you can do a ksort($array), isn't that you want ?

Comment: 'Apr 1-15' is this date period?from 1 till 15 of April?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ksort()` to sort the array:

```
<?php
$array = [
  'Apr 1-15' => [],
  'May 1-15' => [],
  'Apr 16-30' => []
];
ksort($array);
print_r($array);
```

Will output:

```
Array
(
    [Apr 1-15] => Array
        (
        )

    [Apr 16-30] => Array
        (
        )

    [May 1-15] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

Comment: @itachi: different range is not what OP wants. He stated his problem, this is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

> Use usort

```
$aDates = array( 
    'Apr 1-15'  => '',
    'Jan 2'     => '',
    'Feb 4-15'  => '',
    'Dec 28-30' => '',
    'Nov 12-15' => '',
    'Oct 14-15' => '',
    'May 1-15'  => '',
    'Apr 23-30' => '',
    'Apr 2-30'  => '',
    'Apr 4-30'  => ''
);
$aKeys = array_keys( $aDates );
function compareDates( $a, $b )
{
    return strtotime( $a ) - strtotime( $b );
}    
usort( $aKeys, 'compareDates');
var_dump( $aKeys );
```

Returns:

```
// array(10) {
//   [0]=>
//   string(5) "Jan 2"
//   [1]=>
//   string(8) "Feb 4-15"
//   [2]=>
//   string(8) "Apr 1-15"
//   [3]=>
//   string(8) "Apr 2-30"
//   [4]=>
//   string(8) "Apr 4-30"
//   [5]=>
//   string(9) "Apr 23-30"
//   [6]=>
//   string(8) "May 1-15"
//   [7]=>
//   string(9) "Oct 14-15"
//   [8]=>
//   string(9) "Nov 12-15"
//   [9]=>
//   string(9) "Dec 28-30"
// }
```

Comment: It can'n be correct because check `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('Apr 1-15'))`, that means that it convert in wrong way, also Apr 1-15 it is not date,  but date period, I think

Comment: Also, change array values, and result will be incorrect, so re-check

Comment: Check with: $aDates = array( 
  'May 1-15' => '',
  'Apr 16-30' => '',
    'Apr 1-15' => '',
  ); It works wrong, so the algorithm is wrong, it doesn't depends on qty of elements.

Comment: I get array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "Apr 1-15"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "Apr 16-30"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "May 1-15"
}

Answer (score 1):

This code is working fine to me:

```
$data = array(
  'Apr 1-15' => 1,
  'May 1-15' => 2,
  'Apr 16-30' => 3,
 );


uksort($data, function ($a, $b) {
  $a = explode(' ', $a);
  $b = explode(' ', $b);
  return strcasecmp($a[0], $b[0]);
});
foreach ($data as $val)
{
    echo $val."<br />";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you possibly add another array around it, making it a multilevel array, and give each array (containing date-groups and more) a unique id in the correct order they are retrieved/generated?

```
$array = array(
  array(1, array('Apr 1-15', 'more values'),
  array(2, array('Apr 16-30', 'more values'),
  array(3, array('May 1-15', 'more values'),  
);
asort($array);
```

Then *$array[0][0][0]* would equal "Apr 1-15" and *$array[0][0][1]* would equal the second value you choose next to it.